# Android Facebook SDK caption with urls not posted in FB wall

Tags: android, facebook, url, sdk, posting

I can successfully post an image to FB using the following code

```
byte[] data = null;      
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
data = baos.toByteArray();

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("caption", "Test Caption");   
parameters.putString("method", "photos.upload");         
parameters.putByteArray("picture", data);  

AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebookClient);
mAsyncRunner.request(null, parameters, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

But when I try to have a URL in the caption as following

```
 parameters.putString("caption", "Test Caption: http://google.com/");
```

post is not get posted in FB wall

This is also not working

```
parameters.putString("caption", "Test Caption: /");
```

I think the wrong is in sending the / character when posting to the wall.
I want to know is there a way to have url ( or / character) in the caption to post it in FB wall

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the `/` character by putting a forward slash so your string:

> "Test Caption: http://google.com"

should be

> "Test Caption: http:\/\/google.com"

Also,

`mAsyncRunner.request(null, parameters,...`

`null` should be `me/photos`.

Comment: Hi Jesse, I cannot see any different between the code you have suggested and mine for the caption. Can you explain it little bit.

Comment: Ah, stackoverflow's editor messed it up.  I fixed it now, you should see a '\' before each '/'.